# MVC 5 Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication, owin

I have a Web API 2 with bearer token authentication, where an external site authenticates in my api and makes requests by sending the token in the request header, but I also have a MVC 5 Web Site, where authentication should be automatic in this site, the Web API will have a method that redirects to this Web Site and it should already open authenticated, this web site will have just one client, the web api, and the users came authenticated from web api.

**How could I authenticate the web site automatically?** 
**I thought in two different ways to solve this problem:**

1. Use authentication cookies, where I perform a redirect from the web api to the site passing the login information (placed in the web.config, with user and password, or a kind of key), and then, the web site perform the authentication and set a cookie for the browser.
2. Use bearer authentication in both web api and web site (With the same Machine Key on web.config), and when the web api redirect to the web site it pass the bearer token generated for the client, but when the user navigate on the web site, I need to pass this token in the header all the time, and i think that is not a good idea share this token between the web api and the web site, when the navigation ends the process needs to come back to the web api, and will have to authenticate agaIn or pass the same token to the web api.

**Which of these approaches would be the most correct? Or there are some other approach to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

I'd take option 2, you could use a token auth with the claims you need to identify that the incoming request comes from your API. It's stateless, simple and you don't need to pass sensible data among urls